# MemoryLeak in iphone programming?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks, analysis

Can any one help me to understand the problem in this image

[image]

Comment: it's simple just release `locs` before closing braces. and i would like to SAY, REALLY! THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT TO ASK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the analyzer says, you are allocating *locs* on line *647*, using
*`NSMutableArray *locs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`* and not releasing it later in the block. You should release it or you can use convenience constructor to get the autoreleased array like this, *`NSMutableArray *locs = [NSMutableArray array];`*

I'd suggest you to still simplify your code to this,

```
NSMutableArray *annotations = (NSMutableArray *)[map annotations];
[annotations removeObject:[map userLocation]];
[map removeAnnotations:annotations];
```

Comment: can you see the commented lines, I did, but then EXC_BAD_ACCESS :-(

Comment: Even I tried removeAllObjects, and release/nil, but both resulting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Using your code EXC_BAD_ACCESS at     int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

Comment: The problem should be somewhere else. Not in the code you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

You need to release locs at the very end. You have alloc'ed and init'ed it, giving it a reference count of 1, an then you should release it to change the reference count to 0. Refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/ for more info.

Comment: Try only [locs release]; - the other two lines are unneccessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialize the locs array then you have to release that array before closing that function: `[locs release];locs=nil;`

Comment: can you see the commented lines, I did, but then EXC_BAD_ACCESS :-(

Comment: Even I tried removeAllObjects, and release/nil, but both resulting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: I think you add auto release object to locs array in that case only it will happens like this